# HTML video tag won't work in Safari on Windows

Tags: html, video, safari

I've coded a HTML video tag like below. When running the file in Safari browser on Windows OS (Safari version: 5.1.7) the video won't show in my page. I read through several links and understand the end of support for Safari on Windows but wanted to make sure that's indeed the reason for my video tag to not work. I don't have a Mac machine to try this. I tried the tag with .mp4 and .mov and neither would work.

```
     <html>
       <body>
          <video loop controls="true" autoplay width='100%' height='100%' src='D:/safari.mov' type='video/mov'></video>
       </body>
     </html>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you expect you can test how your site is running on a Mac by using Safari for Windows? I doubt that this will work reliably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have Quicktime installed on your machine? If not, an [install](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL837?locale=en_US) and restart should resolve the issue. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @MadGab! Your solution fixed me up!

Comment: I have the player installed now. However I have another problem. When I click on the play button the video won't play. Do you know what could be the reason? I tried with .mp4 and .mov and neither works. Can you pls help?

Comment: @InfiniteLoop would need more info to help. You may want to post a new question with details and some code, rather than trying to resolve it in comments here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a second video file in OGG format so that it works on all browsers, like this:

```
<video loop controls="true" autoplay width='100%' height='100%'>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your video file again with a different software.

Sometimes the video file has issues, and the conversion process fixes it. In my case I used ffmpeg to remove the audio channel, and that fixed the issue with Safari:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.mp4 -an output_file.mp4
```